# Calculating count of records and then appending those counts daily in a separate dataset using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, incremental-load

I have a dynamic dataset like below which is updating everyday. Like on Jan 11 data is:

| Name | Id |
| --- | --- |
| John | 35 |
| Marrie | 27 |

On Jan 12, data is

| Name | Id |
| --- | --- |
| John | 35 |
| Marrie | 27 |
| MARTIN | 42 |

I need to take count of the records and then append that to a separate dataset. Like on Jan 11 my o/p dataset is

| Count | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 11-01-2023 |

On Jan 12 my o/p dataset should be

| Count | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 11-01-2023 |
| 3 | 12-01-2023 |

and so on for all other days whenever the code is ran.

This has to be done using Pyspark

I tried using the semantic_version in the incremental function but it is not giving the desired result.